# BroadcastReceiver не запускается без Activity

Tags: java, android, activity, android-broadcastreceiver

`BroadcastReceiver` можно регистрировать либо в `Activity` (динамически), либо статически (прописывать в манифесте). С первым вопросов нет. Не получается второй способ. Прочитал на сайте, что для того, чтобы манифест зарегистрировался, нужно запустить `Activity`, но так тоже не получается. Решил обратиться к вам за помощью. Вот исходный код:

```
JustBroadcastReceiver.java:

public class JustBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

     public static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(mContext==null) mContext=context;
        StringBuilder strb=new StringBuilder("Текущая дата: ");
        Format fformat=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
        strb.append(fformat.format(new Date()));
        Toast.makeText(context, strb, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
    }    
}

withoutactitivity.xml:

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.withoutactitivity"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity android:name=".JustBroadcastReceiver"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <receiver
            android:name=".JustBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Прочитал на сайте, что нужно запустить активити чтобы манифест зарегился

бегите с такого сайта.

все **Service**'ы и **BroadcastReceiver**`ы, объявленные в манифесте, регистрируются в системе при установке приложения.

а во вторых, обращайте иногда внимание на документацию. в ней все написано:

> public static final String  ACTION_TIME_TICK
>
> Broadcast Action: The current time has changed. Sent every minute. **You can not receive this through components declared in manifests**, only by exlicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver().

Comment: Спасибо большое! Будем знать... Пока еще не привык к англоязычной документации) сделал выводы.